# form post not working due to @HiddenFor in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, field, hidden

for some reason, my form post does not work when i have the hidden field in mvc3 razor. It works fine if i remove the hidden field but i need that field.

Below are my ProductsController post method and razor view

```
@model CCSPurchasing_MVC.Models.AddNewProductModel
    @using CCSPurchasing_MVC.Models
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("editImage", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImadeId) 


    <div class="editor-field">
    <p style="margin-left: 300px; margin-right: 20px;">
           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImageFile)


            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" data-val="true" data-val-required="Product Image is required"/>


    </p>
    </div>

   <input type="submit" value="Edit" /> 



}



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult editImage(AddNewProductModel newP, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{


        db = new DBConnection();
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            newP.ImageName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            newP.ImageType = file.ContentType;
            newP.ImageSize = file.ContentLength;
            newP.ImageFile = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(newP.ImageFile, 0, file.ContentLength);
            newP.ImageHeight = 200;
            newP.ImageWidth = 200;

        }
        string result = db.editImage(newP);    

    return View("editImageUpdate");
}
```

Comment: please share your model

Comment: public class AddNewProductModel
    {
 [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Upload Image")]
        public byte[] ImageFile { get; set; } 
public int ImadeId { get; set; }

}

Comment: Plz add the complete model in your question (not as a comment).

Answer (score 1):

Just make your form tag like this and I am sure it will work for you also as it worked for me when I tested your code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditImage", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"     }))
{
}
```

You need to add enctype = "multipart/form-data" also in your code if you want to submit the file with your fileupload control.